# How do I copy a value from an excel sheet, do something, then repeat again with the next row?

Tags: python

So far what I have is this, I'm attempting to get the value from the 2nd row in column C and G, I use those values to do something, but after that, i'm trying to move to the next row and use those values. I've failed at creating a loop as my code is only using the last values in the columns.
I use the values to copy and paste into a browser to upload files, once the file is uploaded i'm trying to move to the next row.

```
import openpyxl
    
# Specify the path to your Excel file
excel_file_path = 'C:\\Users\\User1\\Downloads\\Dir\\File.xlsx'
# Load the Excel workbook
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_file_path)
# Select the active sheet
sheet = workbook.active

# Find the last row with data in column C (assuming no empty cells in the middle)
last_row_c = sheet.max_row
# Initialize variables to store values from columns C and G
for row in range(2, last_row_c + 1):  # Start from the second row
   # Get values from columns C and G in the current row
   value_c = sheet.cell(row=row, column=3).value
   value_g = sheet.cell(row=row, column=7).value
print(f'Value in column C: {value_c}')
print(f'Value in column G: {value_g}')

' code block for using value c and g in a browser window, uploading file, and returning to get the next values in row 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I can see is, currently, your `print` statements are outside the loop, so they only execute once after the loop has finished. Here’s how you can structure your code:

```
import openpyxl

# Specify the path to your Excel file
excel_file_path = 'C:\\Users\\User1\\Downloads\\Dir\\File.xlsx'

# Load the Excel workbook
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_file_path)
# Select the active sheet
sheet = workbook.active

# Find the last row with data in column C (assuming no empty cells in the middle)
last_row_c = sheet.max_row
# Iterate over each row in columns C and G
for row in range(2, last_row_c + 1):  # Start from the second row
# Get values from columns C and G in the current row
value_c = sheet.cell(row=row, column=3).value
value_g = sheet.cell(row=row, column=7).value

# Perform actions with the values
print(f'Value in column C: {value_c}')
print(f'Value in column G: {value_g}')

# Add your code for using value_c and value_g in a browser window, uploading file, etc.
# Make sure this code is indented inside the loop to execute for each row
```